# component.css-meta.xml File in LWC getting created when retrieved through VS Code

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code, lwc-xml

Due to some recent updates to Salesforce DX or VS Code, I am getting an extra meta.xml file for each Lightning web component which I am trying to retrieve from the source.

For example, if my component name is `component`
then there are two meta XML files getting created after retrieval.

```
component.js-meta.xml
component.css-meta.xml
```

This is the sfdx version I am using/

```
sfdx-cli/7.82.0-3d0c527ac6 win32-x64 node-v12.18.3
```

This is the VS Code version I am using.

```
Version: 1.52.1 (user setup)
Commit: ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523
Date: 2020-12-16T16:34:46.910Z
Electron: 9.3.5
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.2.9200
```

I am not able to deploy the component until I remove the `css-meta.xml` file.

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/761

Answer (score 0):

It's an open bug in the salesforce CLI repo.

For more info:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/761

Comment: Hi Jasneet, glad to see you here, welcome to SFSE, and thank you for helping me out, really appreciate that, but this place is for answers, when you will get enough reputations you will be able to comment on questions.